# SDL.h "Program file does not exist"

Tags: eclipse, sdl, mingw32

I'm pretty new to c++ (and programming in general) and I'm currently trying to inlcude the "SDL.h" header into a c++ project in Eclipse (I use minGW btw). I've provided the project with the paths to the the header files and the library of SDL. However, whenver I specifically include "SDL.h" and the build then project I get the following Message:

" 'Launching SDL Basic.exe' has encountered a problem. Program file does not exist. "

I'm pretty sure that this has to do with the fact that no .exe file is generated whenever I build the project with SDL.h included. What I don't get is why this happens. When I include some other SDL header, such as SDL_assert, this is not a problem. Then the .exe file is generated just as usual and the program runs just as it should.[enter image description here][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdV8U.jpg     How it looks when SDL.h is included.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MW7PX.jpg     How it looks when something else from SDL is included.

Comment: Please provide the full text from the CDT Build Console.  I see undefined reference in your image, but I'm curious how it continues past the edge of the image.  Chances are that the SDL.h header is pulling in code that requires you to link in an external library, so the link operation is failing.

Comment: Okay, so here's the full text: http://imgur.com/XzKZruI

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed the problem. Whenever I ran the program the console window outout " undefined reference to 'Winmain@16' ". So I googled on it and found out that SDL defines its own main function in SDL_main.h, which in total would give me two main functions. To prevent SDL from defining its own main function I had to define the macro SDL_MAIN_HANDLED before I included SDL.h, and look, it worked:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNOOE.jpg

If someone can explain this in more detail I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little research and it looks like the undefined reference to WinMain@16 is because SDL is automatically creating a Windows entry point for your application, but you haven't provided the necessary libraries to link in the SDL implementation of that entry point.  However, if you intend to use the SDL functionality, you really do need that entry point, because it performs several important initialization steps necessary to leverage the SDL features that you presumably want to use.

Defining SDL_MAIN_HANDLED is a mechanism that would allow you to provide your own Windows entry point (i.e.: WinMain), but that is a more complicated approach (albeit more flexible).  This only solves your problem because it happens to prevent "main" from being redefined to "SDL_main" which in turn means that your .cpp file no longer even requires any of the SDL libraries.  So it compiles and links, but you won't have any of the SDL functionality you're looking for.

You need to link in the appropriate libraries.  See [here](https://wiki.libsdl.org/FAQWindows) - it provides some info that might help.